# Signature Library Can't Load Gradle

Tags: android, gradle, signature

I have download a library for signature capturing ( https://github.com/gcacace/android-signaturepad ) and have followed the instruction but still I get an **error**:

> Error:(2, 1) A problem occurred evaluating project ':signature-pad'.
>
> > org/gradle/api/publication/maven/internal/DefaultMavenFactory

this is what I did as what the instruction said:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
apply plugin: 'com.jfrog.bintray'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.gcacace:signature-pad:1.1.0'
}
```

```
 Properties properties = new Properties()
    final def bintrayPropertiesFile = project.rootProject.file('bintray.properties')
    if (bintrayPropertiesFile.exists()) properties.load(bintrayPropertiesFile.newDataInputStream())
```

Or is there any other free signature capturing library for android that you can suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Seems something wrong with android-maven.

Is this line necessary?Delete it and try again:

```
apply plugin: 'com.github.dcendents.android-maven'
```

If it not works,you should run './gradlew build --debug' in terminal for more error info.